# Price Error - Opencart 1.4.3

Tags: opencart

I have a site running Opencart 1.4.3 and currently having an issue with the pricing. If you [visit the site](http://www.combiblind.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=35&product_id=49) you will see that the price is £100. When you use the options you will see the price change to £52.

Currency and location is correct. The £52 pounds is an old value.

Any ideas where next to look?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like either you've got an option with `-48` as the price, or you're getting the value cached somewhere. Try deleting the cache files in `/system/cache/`

Comment: Sadly, no price difference in any option and I have cleared the cache and stays the same

Comment: What about any discounts or "specials" on the product?

Comment: These have expired and also removed

Comment: by the looks of it you have a custom calculation going on via global mega options as you have the width/drop fields

Comment: Been looking around for a custom script/calculator from previous webbie. sadly no prices in the system, think I'm going through a lot of code to find it

Comment: I think you may be right. Might I suggest the /system/library/cart.php file as a first stop as that is most likely where you're going to find it in the getProducts() method

Comment: Cheers Jay - Found the rogue table and code. Need to fix cart and a quote section. *Rolls up sleeves*